# Can jQuery datepicker select more than 10 years ago?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to use jQuery-UI's [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker) to select a birthday, however it only allows me to go back 10 years, i.e. I cannot have users that are older than 10 years :)

I tried to set the `minDate` as follows:

```
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  //minDate: "-100Y", 
  minDate: new Date(1971, 2 - 1, 26),
  maxDate: "+1D" // this works.
});
} );
</script>
```

However I couldn't manage to make it work, the earliest possible selection is always 2007. -How- can I go further back?

Thanks,

Comment: You can go further back - it only lets you go back 10 years at a time. If you check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d0vtr3kf/ you'll see that you can first select 2007, then 1997 etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does go further back, it's just that the dropdown for years is limited to ten years by default.

You can set this using the `yearRange` option

```js
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            //minDate: "-100Y", 
            minDate: new Date(1971, 2 - 1, 26),
            maxDate: "+1D",
            yearRange: '1971:2017',
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use YearRange...

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: "-100:+0",
  //minDate: "-100Y", 
  minDate: new Date(1950, 2 - 1, 26),
  maxDate: "+1D" // this works.
});
```